# GADInterstitial only presenting first time and delegate methods not being called

Tags: ios, admob

I am using Admob for interstitials in my iOS app. I have a test ad set up and it works correctly only the first time I go through the app flow. Subsequent attempts do not show the test ad or call the delegate methods. Below is the `GADInterstitial` ad setup in my `UIViewController`

```
ViewController.h
@interface ViewController : UIViewController <GADInterstitialDelegate>
@property(nonatomic, strong) GADInterstitial *interstitial;



ViewController.m
-(void)viewDidLoad{
    self.interstitial = [[GADInterstitial alloc] initWithAdUnitID:@"ca-app-pub-//adID"];
    self.interstitial.delegate = self;
    GADRequest *request = [GADRequest request];
    // Requests test ads on test devices.
    request.testDevices = @[@"//test device ID"];
    [self.interstitial loadRequest:request];
}
```

I call the ad from an `IBAction`. If the user has paid for the app or has used the `IBAction` under a number of times, then the ad does not show. If user has not paid or used the `IBAction` over a certain number of times, the ad shows. `NSUserDefaults` does the check, and if user does `IBAction` under a certain # of times, fires another method, and increments `NSUserDefaults` to keep track of how many times user has performed action. I tried using other ad networks, and this same `NSUserDefault` check worked fine.

In the ViewController.m `viewDidLoad`.

```
-(void)action{

        if (([[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] integerForKey:@"AdShow"] < 2) || ([[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] integerForKey:@"DidBuyInAppPurchase"] == 1)) {
            [self doOtherAction];
            NSInteger integer = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]integerForKey:@"AdShow"];
            NSInteger newInteger = integer + 1;
            [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setInteger:newInteger forKey:@"AdShow"];

        }
        else{
            NSInteger newInteger = 0;
            [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setInteger:newInteger forKey:@"AdShow"];
            if ([self.interstitial isReady]) {
                [self.interstitial presentFromRootViewController:self];
            }

        }

    }];
}
```

The delegate methods are below also in `viewDidLoad`

```
- (void)interstitialWillPresentScreen:(GADInterstitial *)ad {

}

- (void)interstitialWillDismissScreen:(GADInterstitial *)ad {
    NSLog(@"interstitialWillDismissScreen");
}

- (void)interstitialDidDismissScreen:(GADInterstitial *)ad {
        [self doOtherAction];
}

- (void)interstitial:(GADInterstitial *)ad
didFailToReceiveAdWithError:(GADRequestError *)error {
    [self doOtherAction];

    NSLog(@"interstitial:didFailToReceiveAdWithError: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `GADInterstitial` should go in `viewWillAppear` not `viewDidLoad`. For some reason putting it in `viewDidLoad` causes it not to load with the ad.